# Time Capsule - backup to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, time-capsule

I am trying to get my Time Capsule backuped to iCloud Drive. This so I can secure my files, and to be able to access pic.s etc online through my iPhone/Mac? Anyone have a receipe? I am now using it only as a disk, not a WIFI router.

Comment: I do not believe there is a **built-in way** to backup your Time Machine drive. Though you could probably use something like Super Duper to back it up to a folder that iCloud drive then mirrors. Just remember that there are thousands of files and you could easily saturate your internet connection, at least for the initial backup.

Comment: iCloud Drive is probably not the best product for this.  It's a sync service, not a backup service.  Time Machine is a differential backup - meaning you will have multiple copies of the same file.  If it's just online storage you're looking for, there are cheaper and better options.  If it's online backup - you might do better with iDrive or Carbonite.